# How to increase the max_connections value for MySQL on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: configuration, ubuntu-14.04, configuration-files, mysql-5.6, my.cnf

I use MySQL `5.6` on Ubuntu Server `14.04` and want to increase the maximal allowed number of simultaneous connections (currently set to default `151`).

Responsible for this is the setting `max_connections` in the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. So I set it to `200` and restarted the MySQL server. Now, it has the value `200`:

```
$ cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf | grep "connections"
max_connections        = 200
$ /etc/init.d/mysql restart
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                             [ OK ] 
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                             [ OK ] 
 * Checking for tables which need an upgrade, are corrupt or were 
not closed cleanly.
```

But nothing has changed:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections";
+-----------------+-------+
¦ Variable_name   ¦ Value ¦
+-----------------+-------+
¦ max_connections ¦ 151   ¦
+-----------------+-------+
```

**How to get the custom configuration of `max_connections` working?**

---

```
$ ulimit -a | grep "open"
open files                      (-n) 1024
$ ulimit -n 4096
$ ulimit -a | grep "open"
open files                      (-n) 4096
```

added to the `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
* soft nofile 1024000
* hard nofile 1024000
* soft nproc 10240
* hard nproc 10240
root soft nproc unlimited
```

added to the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld_safe]
open_files_limit = 1024000
[mysqld]
open_files_limit = 1024000
```

But it seems to be ignored:

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'open%';
+--------------------------+-------+
¦ Variable_name            ¦ Value ¦
+--------------------------+-------+
¦ Open_files               ¦ 52    ¦
+--------------------------+-------+
¦ Open_streams             ¦ 0     ¦
+--------------------------+-------+
¦ Open_table_definitions   ¦ 434   ¦
+--------------------------+-------+
¦ Open_tables              ¦ 417   ¦
+--------------------------+-------+
¦ Opened_files             ¦ 847   ¦
+--------------------------+-------+
¦ Opened_table_definitions ¦ 0     ¦
+--------------------------+-------+
¦ Opened_tables            ¦ 0     ¦
+--------------------------+-------+
```

To avoid the case of setting the correct configs in wrong files I set the option in all these files (some of them was not there, so I created them):

```
$ mysqld --help --verbose | grep -B 1 cnf
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

No effect.

Answer (score 3):

```
[mysqld]
```

max_connections = 400

max_user_connections=300

you have to add max_connections property as below to the [mysqld]. for me its working..

Answer (score 1):

You will have to increase open files limit on your OS, and afterwards, you can put higher max_connections value.

Comment: Just done (`ulimit -n 4096`) and restarted MySQL. No effect.